# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent - referencing different schema from validation says that schema does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.1

I have a schema called `public`. Inside this schema I have a table called `currencies`.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Lapis\Domain\Currency;

use Lapis\Domain\Core\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class EloquentCurrency
 *
 * @package Lapis\Domain\Currency
 */
class EloquentCurrency extends Model implements CurrencyInterface
{
    /**
     * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'public.currencies';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'symbol',
        'code',
        'decimal_places',
    ];
}
```

Everything works perfectly due to setting `$table` as `public.currencies`. I can perform all CRUD operations through repository or directly in my controller.

What seems to be broken is trying to use `exists` rule.

In my validator I have:

```
'name' => [
    'required',
    'exists:public.currencies',
],
```

This is just an excerpt. Final validation will be much more complex but the issue is that Laravel is unable to see the table when I call it like `public.currencies`.

Apparently syntax

> schema.table

doesn't work. Any ideas why? I can solve this my using custom validation and using custom repository method to check if exists but I wanted to use native method.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that your database configuration has no **key value** defined for a **public** connection. Check your `config/databases.php` file & specify a connection with **public** as connection name (for example with MySQL as driver):

```
'connections' => [

    ...

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
],
```

Alternatively you may also ommit the connection from your validation rule, if the connection you're intending to validate with is your default connection as mentioned in the Laraval docs:

> **Custom Database Connection**
>
> Occasionally, you may need to set a custom connection for database queries made by the Validator. As seen above, setting `unique:users` as a validation rule will use the default database connection to query the database. To override this, specify the connection followed by the table name using "dot" syntax: